# how to add a constraint that checks multiple rows of information?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I need to make a `CONSTRAINT` that checks data on multiple rows, an **indefinite amount of them**.
I've seen that `CHECK` can only reach data inside the current row, and I have also seen that to solve this problem you need to declare a function (or something that looks just like one).

For clarification:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ownership`(
`owner_id` INT,
`property_id` INT,
`share` DECIMAL(5,4),
 CONSTRAINT `chk_share` CHECK (`share` <= 1.0 AND `share` >= 0),
 --CONSTRAINT
 -- `share` should show the percentage of the property owner owns
 -- I want to add a constraint that does not allow the sum of all
 -- ownership rows with the same property_id be greater than 1.

 PRIMARY KEY(`owner_id`, `property_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_owner`
    FOREIGN KEY(`owner_id`)
    REFERENCES `market`.`entity` (`entity_id`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_property`
    FOREIGN KEY(`property_id`)
    REFERENCES `market`.`entity` (`entity_id`)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I did not find this question answered on this site, so I am asking politely.
I use MySQL Workbench.

Comment: You'd do this with a before insert and update trigger. `select sum(share) + NEW.share from ownership where property_id = ? group by property` and raise if it is greater than 1.

Comment: @Schwern got it, haven't heard of triggers yet. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Schwern said I used a trigger.

```sql
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `tgr_share`
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON `market`.`ownership`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF ( SELECT SUM(`share`) + NEW.`share` 
             FROM `market`.`ownership` 
             WHERE `property_id` = NEW.`property_id` 
             GROUP BY `property_id` > 1.0 ) 
        THEN 
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ownership total shares > 1';
        END IF;
    END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

I tested it and it works as intended.

Since I needed to use it with both insert and update, the code bellow works even better:

```sql
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE `fn_share` (`new_share` DECIMAL(5,4), `new_property_id` INT)

    BEGIN
        IF ( SELECT SUM(`share`) + `new_share` 
            FROM `market`.`ownership` 
            WHERE `property_id` = `new_property_id` 
            GROUP BY `property_id` > 1.0) 
        THEN 
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ownership total shares > 1';
        END IF;
    END;
|

DELIMITER ;

CREATE TRIGGER `tgr_share_insert`
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON `market`.`ownership`
    FOR EACH ROW
    CALL `fn_share`(NEW.`share`, NEW.`property_id`);;

CREATE TRIGGER `tgr_share_update`
    BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON `market`.`ownership`
    FOR EACH ROW
    CALL `fn_share`(NEW.`share`, NEW.`property_id`);;
```